# Init Selenium RC on headless server

Tags: headless, selenium

as described in [1] running Selenium RC on a headless Linux is pretty easy to achieve. Essentially this requires these commands:

```
$ Xvfb :99 -ac &
$ export DISPLAY=:99 
$ java -jar selenium-server.jar &
```

So how can I provide this right after the start of the server?

The system is a Ubuntu Server 10.04.

Cheers

[1] http://www.alittlemadness.com/2008/03/05/running-selenium-headless/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using http://code.google.com/p/semicomplete/source/browse/xdotool/t/ephemeral-x.sh pretty much solves it - so within selenium a browser setting like "*firefox /usr/local/bin/ephemeral-firefox.sh" worked for me with these lines within ephemeral-firefox.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
/urs/local/bin/ephemeral-x.sh firefox $*
```

Cheers

Comment: The above link gives a 404.  The project has been moved to https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/blob/master/t/ephemeral-x.sh